# How to convert a file path to IFormFIle in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do i get an IFormFile Instance using a file path?. The file, in this case is an **Image** stored in the **`wwwroot`** folder.

I'll give you a little bit of context of what i am trying to achieve:
I want to update a product so in order to do that i have to display the product information on the view, including it's file name next to the `<input type="file" class="form-control-file" asp-for="File">`. So the user knows,it has already an image, and of course i won't have problem doing the HTTP Post Request because no file was selected (In case the user doesn't want to update the image). The problem is that product class doesn't have an IFormFile property, it only has it's image name, and the view model is responsible of having the IForm File. So again how do i convert the image name or path into a IFormFile before sending the productViewModel as a parameter to the View?

Here's my view,view model and my product class:
**`Update.cshtml`**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name" placeholder="Cereal, Ice cream, Tuna, etc...">
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="File"></label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" asp-for="File">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

**`ProductViewModel.cshtml`**

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

**`Product.cshtml`**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why you can not another another property `ImageName` in viewmodel? You don't need to set `IFormFile` in C# code. You need to use that only for getting file from the client to server.

Comment: I would also suggest you to provide the information that there already is an existing file using a separate property. Fiddling with file inputs is very tricky (for security reasons) and it won’t allow you to arbitrarily set its value anyway, even if there was a way to pass on the IFormFile back to the view.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a demo to change path to IFormFile in Action:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult GetFile() {
            Product product = new Product { Name = "product1", ImageName = "red.PNG" };
            string path = "./wwwroot/images/" + product.ImageName;
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                ProductViewModel productViewModel = new ProductViewModel
                {
                    Name = product.Name,

                    File = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
                };
                return Ok();
            }
            
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Getting access to the path is denied. c# .net core